# Ruby regex to split on multiple delimeters

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to split a string that contains both a comma and the word 'and'.

Example:

'one, two and three'

I can get a split working on the comma or the 'and', but not both.

Could anyone help please?

The closest I got was:

```
str = 'one, two and three'

str.split(/,\W+/)

> ["one", "two and three"]
```

Comment: [Alternation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187880/what-does-the-pipe-character-mean-in-a-regular-expression/22187948#22187948).

Comment: That simple!! Thank you